# Creating an hour range row

Tags: r, time

I am currently working with data from food trucks and it is organised by the Applicant, the day of the week it is open, the starting hour and the ending hour.

I have been asked to make either separate rows or columns that would depict if an hour occurred within the range of the starting hour and the ending hour (Open, Not Open).

Is there a way to ask R to return, for every hour of the day, which hours fall within the range of the starting hour and ending hour and label it open. Then to ask it to the same thing with every hour that is not within the range and label it Not Open.

I attempted to use a for loop but was not successful.

```
for(Yes in c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14",
             "15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24"))
{
    print(Yes)
    if(Yes %in% (NSFS$starthour %between% NSFS$endhour))
}



DayOfWeekStr Applicant           starthour  endhour  locationid
Friday       Natan's Catering    12         13       437207
Friday       Linda's Catering    10         15       760539
Wednesday    Mang Hang Catering  12         13       559779
Sunday       Tacos Santana       17         22       453014
Friday       Breaking Bread Inc. 14         18       934995
```

Comment: Can you specify what the end hour is? A bit confused by the question

Comment: For example, start hour would be 14 and end hour would 22 so the food truck would open from 2:00PM to 10:00PM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have an input table with start_hour and end_hour being integers, e.g.:

```
#  applicant    day start_hour end_hour
#1         a monday          9       10
#2         a monday         12       12
#3         a monday         14       16
#4         a monday         17       18
```

You can use `seq` to find all hours between start and end. The idea in the following code is to generate one `data.table` with the open hours (`dt_open_hours`) and one `data.table` (`dt_all_hours`) with all possible hours (using the applicants and days in the input data). By merging the two data.tables the resulting table will contain all possible combinations of `applicant`, `day` and `hour`, but the state (Open / Not Open) will only come from `dt_open_hours`. The final step is to convert missing values (`NA`) to "Not Open":

```
library(data.table)
dt <- structure(list(applicant = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "a", class = "factor"), 
  day = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "monday", class = "factor"), 
  start_hour = c(9L, 12L, 14L, 17L), end_hour = c(10L, 12L, 
  16L, 18L)), .Names = c("applicant", "day", "start_hour", 
  "end_hour"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

# Convert to data.table
setDT(dt)
# Assign row_id unique row_ids for seq to work on one row at a time
dt[, row_id := seq(1, nrow(dt))]
# Convert start and end hour into sequence of hours between start and end
dt_open_hours <- dt[, .(state = "Open",
                      hour = as.integer(seq(from = start_hour, to = end_hour, by = 1))),
  by = .(row_id, applicant, day)]
# Remove row_id column
dt_open_hours[, row_id := NULL]
# Generate data.table with all combinations of applicant, day and hour
dt_all_hours <- CJ(applicant = unique(dt_open_hours[, applicant]),
                   day = unique(dt_open_hours[, day]), hour = seq(1, 24))
# Merge
out <- dt_open_hours[dt_all_hours, on=.(applicant, day, hour)]
out[is.na(state), state := "Not Open"]
```

The `out` data.table looks like this:

```
#    applicant    day    state hour
# 1:         a monday Not Open    1
# 2:         a monday Not Open    2
# 3:         a monday Not Open    3
# 4:         a monday Not Open    4
# 5:         a monday Not Open    5
# 6:         a monday Not Open    6
# 7:         a monday Not Open    7
# 8:         a monday Not Open    8
# 9:         a monday     Open    9
#10:         a monday     Open   10
#11:         a monday Not Open   11
#12:         a monday     Open   12
#13:         a monday Not Open   13
#14:         a monday     Open   14
#15:         a monday     Open   15
#16:         a monday     Open   16
#17:         a monday     Open   17
#18:         a monday     Open   18
#19:         a monday Not Open   19
#20:         a monday Not Open   20
#21:         a monday Not Open   21
#22:         a monday Not Open   22
#23:         a monday Not Open   23
#24:         a monday Not Open   24
#    applicant    day    state hour
```

**Update:** using the following updated input data.frame:

```
  DayOfWeekStr           Applicant starthour endhour locationid
1       Friday    Natan's Catering        12      13     437207
2       Friday    Linda's Catering        10      15     760539
3    Wednesday  Mang Hang Catering        12      13     559779
4       Sunday       Tacos Santana        17      22     453014
5       Friday Breaking Bread Inc.        14      18     934995
```

A few modifications were made to the code (beyond using the column names provided in the updated input data.frame), mainly to incorporate the `locationid` variable: `dt_open_hours` contains the hours between `starthour` and `endhour` for each unique combination of `Applicant`, `DayOfWeekStr`, `locationid` (`locationid` is new), and `dt_all_hours` contains hours 1 to 24 for the same unique combinations of `Applicant`, `DayOfWeekStr`, `locationid`. Merging of `dt_open_hours` and `dt_all_hours` is done on `Applicant`, `DayOfWeekStr`, `locationid`, and `hour` (`locationid` is new).

```
library(data.table)
dt <- structure(list(DayOfWeekStr = c("Friday", "Friday", "Wednesday", 
  "Sunday", "Friday"), Applicant = c("Natan's Catering", "Linda's Catering", 
  "Mang Hang Catering", "Tacos Santana", "Breaking Bread Inc."), 
  starthour = c(12L, 10L, 12L, 17L, 14L), endhour = c(13L, 
  15L, 13L, 22L, 18L), locationid = c(437207L, 760539L, 559779L, 
  453014L, 934995L)), .Names = c("DayOfWeekStr", "Applicant", 
  "starthour", "endhour", "locationid"), row.names = c(NA, -5L),
  class = "data.frame")

# Convert to data.table
setDT(dt)
# Assign row_id unique row_ids for seq to work on one row at a time
dt[, row_id := seq(1, nrow(dt))]
# Convert start and end hour into sequence of hours between start and end
dt_open_hours <- dt[, .(state = "Open",
                        hour = as.integer(seq(from = starthour, to = endhour, by = 1))),
                    by = .(row_id, Applicant, DayOfWeekStr, locationid)]
# Remove row_id column
dt_open_hours[, row_id := NULL]
# Generate data.table with all combinations of applicant, day and hour
dt_all_hours <- dt[, .(hour = seq(1, 24)),
                  by = . (Applicant, DayOfWeekStr, locationid)]
# Merge
out <- dt_open_hours[dt_all_hours,
                     on=.(Applicant, DayOfWeekStr, locationid, hour)]
out[is.na(state), state := "Not Open"]
```

Comment: Thank you, the example works perfectly! I do have one issue however. As I have nearly 500 variables, it wouldn't be expedient to input them all by hand. Is there a way to instruct R to go through each variable and pick the information?

Comment: You are welcome! Please provide a minimal example of your input data (to understand the structure of the data). Are the 500 variables stored in data frame columns? Does the data span a single week? If not, how do you distinguish data from e.g. monday one week from data from monday another week?

Comment: I edited my original question to include a small sample of the data input. I hope that helps!